# How to show local notification when find bluetooth device in background in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, background-process, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS (Objective-c) application, and I connect a key chain bluetooth. Then I connect this, I want press the home button of my iPhone (so app go to background) and then, send an UILocalNotification when keychain will be detected by CoreBluetooth again.

I have read any post of this, and is possible, because is from background and it's could be possible to do. But I can't show this notification because not scan then press home button and exists function like `willRestoreState` give us by Apple...

This is my code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@import CoreBluetooth;
@interface AppDelegate () <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.centralManager.delegate = self;
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"BF8D9479-FC81-40EE-A9A7-A9AC78E2707D"}];
    //Used to debug CM restore only
    NSArray *centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %lu", @"Manager Restores: ", (unsigned long)centralManagerIdentifiers.count];
    NSLog(@"finish");
    [self sendNotification:str];
    for(int i = 0;i<centralManagerIdentifiers.count;i++)
    {
        [self sendNotification:(NSString *)[centralManagerIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)state {
    //NSArray *peripherals = state[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey];

    CBPeripheral *activePeripheral = [state[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] firstItem];
    activePeripheral.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"willRestore");
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", @"Device: ", activePeripheral.identifier.UUIDString];
    [self sendNotification:str];
}

-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState called");
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // error handling
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"scanning for peripherals");
        //following call will result in callback to centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral ...
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[@"BF8D9479-FC81-40EE-A9A7-A9AC78E2707D"] options:options];
    }
}

//sendNotification is a func that creates a local notification for debugging when device connected to comp
-(void)sendNotification: (NSString *)string{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];
    notification.alertBody = @"Hi! Slide to open the app :)";
    notification.soundName =  @"Alarm-Clock.caf";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    NSLog(@"Back back");

}

    - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    CBPeripheral* currentPer = peripheral;
    NSLog(@"Discorvery");
    if(![cbArray containsObject:currentPer])
    {
        [cbArray addObject:currentPer];

        if([currentPer.name containsString:@"blue"]){
            NSLog(@"CurrentPer Nombre: %@", currentPer.name);
            NSLog(@"CurrentPer UDID: %@", currentPer.identifier.UUIDString);
            [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:currentPer options:nil];
            [self sendNotification:@"awdwad"];
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The keychain is completely compatible with CoreBluetooth, is a intelligent key chain anti-lost 4.0, and it has a button. 
And I have added the keys in my .plist with background mode and bluetooth use.

Comment: Normally you would keep a connection to the peripheral.  When the peripheral disconnects you immediately try to reconnect. As long as you have Bluetooth background mode then you will get a call to your didConnect delegate method when the peripheral comes back into range and is connected. In that function you can post a local notification.

Comment: But with my code I print status with NSLog, and when I press home button only print NSLog(@"Back back");, not keep calling didDiscoverPeripheral and I don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: You wouldn't discover the peripheral; you have already discovered the peripheral. You should maintain a connection to it. You cannot receive duplicate discovery notifications in the background.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understood you. where should I instantiate the declaration to discover the peripheral?? I declare this when star application in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and it works. But this not continue then go to background

Comment: You discover the peripheral as usual, then you connect to it.  When/if you get a disconnect notification, issue another connect to the same peripheral immediately.  If the device comes back into range, then the connection will complete and your delegate method will be called.  Simply attempting to discover the peripheral's advertisement in the background won't work.